# MySql Run sql method every day

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

In my sql i have two tables:
Events
History

That have the same columns exactly,and have a column that called `date` that have `DateTime` value.

And i want that every day in the night something like 03:00 run a method that move all the expaired expired rows from Events to History.

I understand that there is two ways to do it:

1)build c# service that run every day.

2)add event to MySql that run every day.

What is the better way to do it?
and there is any good tutorial for this?

Comment: Can you not create an `SSIS Package` or use a Windows `Scheduler` to do this task..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention .net I assume you run under windows.

- You might also consider scheduling a task using the windows task scheduler. It's in all versions of windows. If you're using v7 just type 'schedule' into the search area by the start button.
- You can easily write a powershell script, or use the mysql command line tool, to execute a sql statement of your choice. Use the scheduler to start it when desired.